# If I execute a native `SELECT *` SQL statement using Hibernate, will the order of the results always match the order of the columns in the table?

Tags: java, hibernate

### Context:

- This is a `Jersey` application
- Run on a `Tomcat` server
- Connects to a `MySQL` database using `Hibernate`
- All on `Netbeans`

I have a table that may potentially have many columns. Each column is an integer representing a tally for some metric. I need to be able to query for a list of all the columns, and match them to their appropriate metric id in code -- right now the metric id will be the name of the column.

The way I'm planning on implementing this is having an array containing all the metric ids. Where the index of a particular id is the column position of the corresponding tally in the database. I'd use a for loop to iterate through the arrays, and create the `HashMap` I need by doing:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> tallies = new HashMap<>();

//i start at 1 instead of 0 because the first result in the hibernate
//results array will be the primary key of the record; not a tally
for (int i=1; i < hibernateResults.length; i++){
    tallies.put(metricIds[i], new Tally(hibernateResults[i]));
}
```

So basically this whole implementation fails if Hibernate doesn't deliver the columns in the order they're structured in the database every single time.

Any chance that may happen?

Comment: Could someone **ever** run `ALTER TABLE`? Cause that'll break it too.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch anyone managing the database in the future would be made very aware of the consequences of altering this table in a way that would break the implementaion, but as of right now, no. it's just me using this database